# Tensorflow default data format in GPU

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working on Tensorflow with GPU. I was curious about data format of tensor. I thought that data are stored in GPU/CPU in Row Major.

However, if I want to store the data in column-major in one operation(Op), can I change the data format only for that operation(Op)? (ex. put some options in function indicates change the format of data)

For instance in `matmul` operation, there exist options related to transpose. Is there any change in data format (Column Major / Row Major) if I transpose the matrix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the default data format is [row-major](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/90033a0c87bb3d289144cbd429a9067a4a4881d6/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_types.h#L90-L92) which is opposite to [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html).

If you are using Python, then you will need to [transpose your data](http://devdocs.io/tensorflow~python/tf/transpose) when *simulating* a col-major layout. When using C++ nothing prevents you from employing `Eigen::RowMajor` instead.

The `matmul` has options `transpose_a` and `transpose_b` as (cu-)BLAS can handle both formats without explicit transpose, e.g. see GEMM. So it will *not* change your data format. It is only a trick, to prevent additionals launch of CUDA kernels or other functions beforehand to minimize run-time.

It is part of the BLAS specification, [e.g. see LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/d54/group__double__blas__level3_gaeda3cbd99c8fb834a60a6412878226e1.html#gaeda3cbd99c8fb834a60a6412878226e1)

Comment: Thanks for reply in details. As I understand, data will be stored in row major when I use c++ regardless of devices(GPU/CPU), right?